# Disable Safe Mode for Newer OS

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, regedit, safe-mode

To block standard users to log in , We are applying below reg key for Win11 Computers via GPO. But its not working. standard users Still log in to computer via safe mode.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System

SafeModeBlockNonAdmins

REG_DWORD 0x00000001 (1)
```

Comment: @John - [it’s absolutely possible to prevent the ability to boot into Safe Mode unless you are an Administrator](https://www.cyber.gov.au/acsc/view-all-content/publications/hardening-microsoft-windows-10-version-21h1-workstations). Have not found the DoD CISA equivalent

Comment: @Cell-o - Windows 11 Home or Professional?

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 11 Enterprise

Comment: So there are two possibilities. I can’t find any Microsoft page on this policy, so it could have changed, because it’s strange I was able to find a Australia Cyber page on the policy. The second possibility it doesn’t completely disable it. What way were you testing if Safe Mode was possible?

Comment: I want to block non-admin users.

Comment: According to the https://terrytlslau.tls1.cc/2013/04/block-standard-users-to-log-in-on.html ,it was possible for legacy OS.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, Safe mode will stay accessible via `msconfig`.

Since entering Safe mode requires a reboot, an idea might be on the
shutdown event to undo the option to boot into Safe mode,
using this command:

```
bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot
```

Note that, if this idea works, for you to enter Safe mode would require
booting into the Command Prompt mode and use `bcdedit /set` to set the
option, or even to boot from a Windows boot media.
This method will require much testing before using it.

Comment: [it’s absolutely possible to prevent the ability to boot into Safe Mode unless you are an Administrator](https://www.cyber.gov.au/acsc/view-all-content/publications/hardening-microsoft-windows-10-version-21h1-workstations). Have not found the DoD CISA equivalent

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, this is said to work, but it doesn't work for the poster in Windows 11.